# Program Icons bounce, but won't open on Apple MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, dmg, archive, zip, rar

I just got an Apple MacBook Pro that is 5 years old and I have no idea how to use it or if something is wrong with it. I have 10.9.5 and it's supposed to be compatible and it didn't work. Since then, I've gotten 3 more programs from a total of 4 different places and they all do the same thing, so this isn't a problem just with one program or place. 2 of them had to be unzipped, then there was a rar file inside them that had to be extracted. The other 2 programs were marked7z; I unzipped them, then used the rar/zip extractor I got from the Apple store(i've used 4 different ones). Everything seems to work fine until I try to open the programs. I click or double-click on them, they say verifying, the bar fills, then the icon just bounces up and down on the desktop dock and the programs never open. I've uninstalled and erased everything, then downloaded them again and still same problem. They all just bounce, but never actually open. After waiting 5-10 minutes, I right-click and select force quit. I've inspected contents and everything looks fine; hash is correct; I can't figure out what's wrong. One of the programs has a .dmg and an .iso and when I click that them, they both say it isn't recognized. Am I doing something wrong with the extract/archive?

I've never had an Apple before, but it seems like it should be easier than this to just download install and open a program.

Comment: Let's edit this down to have even 1/3 of the text it has now. Let's pick one specific app and then we wan try to help you. Then you can ask follow on questions for each subsequent app until you're at a spot where you understand how app downloads can break or what step was needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely because the app's binary is missing the execute bit. In Terminal, run the following:

```
chmod +x "/Applications/AppName.app/Contents/MacOS/AppName"
```

Replace the first 'AppName' with the name of the app and second with the name of the app's binary. You can find this by right clicking on the app, choosing Show Package Contents, then opening Contents → MacOS.

Comment: this site wont let me say certain things. sucks. i quit this sh***y site. rather take 2 days to figure it out myself. cant edit comments, add certain tags, or ask certain questions with certain words in it until i have cyber street cred. this is retard

Comment: thanks anyway, but i cant get help if i'm not allowed to say certain words. i don't understand why me 1st amendment rights are being taken just because i am a new user. i'm literally shaking. this site is oppressing new users and taking advantage of us. i will let my tumblr friends know and we will wage war on this so-called "stackexchange", which is in reality, just a patriarchal system for experienced based bias to flourish, unencumbered. stackexchange is a cowardly website run by privileged users.